# How to reassign a wxImage pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, wxwidgets, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm trying to create a kind of image editor in wxWidgets and I load and store the image in a wxImage pointer. As the user click a button it suppose to delete the pointer and assign them again to a new wxImage. The code I use look like this.

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame {
  wxImage *old_image;
  void OnLoad(wxCommandEvent &event);
};

void MyFrame::OnLoad(wxCommandEvent &event) {
  // Get the image path with wxFileDialog and read it.

  wxImage *new_image = new wxImage(new_width,
                                   new_height,
                                   image_data);

  // old_image->Destroy(); // I think this also work
  delete old_image;
  old_image = new_image;
}
```

I know the code works the first time I load a new image, but by the second time it hangs and crash the application. So I think the error is not in the load algorithm.

How I suppose to delete the wxImage?
Or there is a more reliable way to change the image?

I'm using wxWidgets 3.0.5, MinGW-w64 with gcc 8.0.1

Comment: Do you have ahard crash or an assert?

Comment: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_image.html#a2c97634b43bdd143f34418fb1f98a690

Comment: I think is a crash, because there is no message and the app just close like it was closed via Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1):

With that constructor, `wxImage` will take ownership of `image_data` and will *free* it when deleted. In order to reuse it, you must pass `true` to the 4th argument (`static_data`, see the docs).

Comment: Ok, I made that change but the problem persist, the app hangs and closes itself. I tried to also use SetData() but won work.

Comment: You should probably show more code, i.e. what you are doing with `image_data`.

Comment: Actually, `image_data` is an `unsigned char *` which OpenCV generates,but the only objetive of OpenCV it's to generate that data, and the data it's only used when the `MyFrame::Onload()` loads it to the `wxImage`

Comment: That's still not enough information. OpenCV should probably handle it as `unsigned char **` -- does it? Or maybe the generated data is not always `new_width`x`new_height`. If you only use the data from the first iteration, does it continue to show the initial image?

Comment: No, OpenCV works with the data as `cv::Mat<unsigned char>`, and I use OpenCV functions to obtain an `unsigned char *` for wxWidgets use.

And No, it does not work, if I load the same image it crash also. All the image data that OpenCV returns and reads are always the same size I verified and check it several times.